# Align vertical section level in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

How can I align vertically in section level in Word? I saw a lot of tutorial but Page Setup - Layout - Vertical Alignment is not enough for me. It's hard to explain in words so I attach an image to describe my expectation

[image: Vertical alignment section]

Comment: For the characters, I suggest you try the [Spacing (Before, After)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIbKe.png) to have a check. For the images, I suggest you try the [Position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xmpI.png) settings.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that what you want is **Justified alignment**.

[image]

Note the "Applies to" box. This can apply to the whole document or a single section.

*Otherwise, with each paragraph you can set space before/after.*